# Triggers when using sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Hi i need help with triggers. I am a newbie to coding therefore am seeking advice.

I have 2 tables

NEW and OLD

All the data from NEW needs to be transfered into OLD and New data needs to be put into the NEW Table.

The change will happen when it hits a specific date and time.

I have no idea of approaching this, any help i would really appreciate it!

J

Answer (score 5):

> *The change will happen when it hits a specific date and time.*

Triggers **cannot** be executed at a **given time**. Triggers will execute **always** after an `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` (or combinations thereof) statement, or **always** `INSTEAD OF INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`.

What you're talking about - synchronizing two tables at a given specific time of day - would be best handled by a SQL Agent Job that kicks off e.g. a stored procedure that would do this merge from `NEW` to `OLD`.

Comment: Thanks Marc, so i need to ready into a SQL Agent Job, how would i do the merge? do you have any examples of code or website links,

Comment: Also i am not implementing this, i just need to have the code written and if i highlight and execute this it can do it.

Answer (score 0):

**Read this**

```
kindly first decide the date interval 

then use a simple SP for inserting/updating

the new record.

GO to sql jobs add then SP and schedule the date interval.

No need trigger
```